# P.E. and weight of object in constant speed

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, weight

1. If an object from rest is lifted up in the air by putting it into palm with constant speed $v$ what is its kinetic and potential energy of that object?
2. As the object moving with constant speed (no acceleration) can we use P.E = mgh to find the potential energy?
3. If the applying force is equal to gravitational force (weight of that object) then what causes the object to lift up?

Comment: $PE=mgh$ always works. Regardless of constant speed or not.

Comment: Regarding you point 3., you are confusing force into motion. Force does not cause motion - it causes *changes* in motion. For something to move up, you don't need any net force. You only need a net force to make it move faster or slower. Have a look at Newton's 2nd law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The kinetic energy is $K = \frac{mv^2}{2}$ and, assuming the gravitational field is approximately constant, the gravitational potential energy is $U = mgh$
2. Yes, we can. The gravitational potential energy is just the work done by the weight force when the object is released from that height, which is still the same. You can also understand it in terms of $W_{C} = - \Delta U$. That is, the work done by the conservative forces equals minus the variation of potential energy. Since the work done by the weight - which is the only conservative force in this situation - is negative, the variation of the potential energy is positive and you *are* gaining energy (because work is being done on the object you are lifting).
3. When you started lifting the object, necessarily the force of your hand was bigger than the weight. Otherwise, there would be no acceleration for the object's velocity changes from zero to pointing upwards. Only after this small moment, we can assume the resulting force is zero. In this situation, the acceleration of the object is zero, but the velocity isn't. Therefore, it keeps moving upwards due to Newton's First Law of Motion (the Principle of Inertia). Be careful, you don't need forces to keep something moving (though the greeks thought so).

Comment: Nickolas Alves, you mean we just need a small force that is slightly greater than the weight of that object. once the object comes into motion the object will keep into motion by the law of inertia and the net force acting on the object is zero (by assuming that the slightly greater force is infinitesimally small).

Comment: @UmarKhanLecturerMathematics I believe that the force cannot be constant in this situation, since there are no infinitesimals in the actual world (since it is quantized). However, I guess your way of stating it is correct, assuming only Classical Mechanics.